# Loading a polymorphic model recursive with conditions

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I try to eager load a polymorphic model with some conditions that's connected to two other models and having some problems.

My models:

```
class One extends Model {

    public function twos() {
        return $this->hasMany(Two::class);
    }

    public function threes() {
        return $this->morphMany(Three::class, 'threeable');
    }
}


class Two extends Model {

    public function one() {
        return $this->belongsTo(One::class);
    }

    public function threes() {
        return $this->morphMany(Three::class, 'threeable');
    }
}

class Three extends Model {

    public function threeable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

So far everythings is everything great: I've a lot of `One` items that have a lot of `Two` relations and both have even more `Three` relations (on its own).

Now I try to get the latest `Three` from `Two`, where it also can come from a `One` relation (highest threes.updated_at from either A or B).

The *threes* table looks something like this

```
| id | threeable_id | threeable_type | updated_at |
|---|---|---|---|
| 1 | 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | A | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | B | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | B | 4 |
| 5 | 2 | A | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | A | 4 |
| 7 | 2 | B | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | B | 3 |
```

I want threes.id = 4 for `B::find(1)->withC()` and threes.id = 6 for `B::find(2)->withC()`.

For performance reasons I want to load it in one query (I'm loading multiple `Two` and want the related `Three` and don't want to fire an own query for that). So I tried to put it in a scope (in class `Two`). Joining on the `Three` table and doing some max on the updated_at in a sub query ... It was a total mess and didn't worked that well

It didn't really feel the "Laravel-way" neither :(

Thanks for any help

**EDIT**

Maybe as an addition here's the pure SQL

```
SELECT twos.id, threes.id
FROM
(SELECT
    twos.id twoId, MAX(th.updated_at) threeMaxUA
FROM
    twos

LEFT JOIN (SELECT
    th.*
FROM
    (SELECT
        threeable_id, threeable_type, MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at
    FROM
        threes
    WHERE
        deleted_at IS NULL
    GROUP BY threeable_id , threeable_type) thmax
        LEFT JOIN
    threes pr ON (th.threeable_id = thmax.threeable_id
        AND th.updated_at = thmax.updated_at
        AND th.threeable_type = thmax.threeable_type)
GROUP BY th.threeable_id , th.threeable_type) th

ON
(
    (th.threeable_id = twos.id AND th.threeable_type = 'App\\Two')
        OR
    (th.threeable_id = twos.product_id AND th.threeable_type = 'App\\One')
)

GROUP BY twos.id
) twthmax

LEFT JOIN twos ON twos.id = twthmax.twoId

LEFT JOIN threes ON (
    twthmax.threeMaxUA = threes.updated_at
    AND 
    (
        (threes.threeable_id = twos.id AND threes.threeable_type = 'App\\Two')
            OR
        (threes.threeable_id = twos.product_id AND threes.threeable_type = 'App\\One')
    )
)
```